# opensuse (tumbleweed) + nginx + codeigniter 404 issue

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, opensuse

I've been fighting with this for a while now ans still cannot get it to run. I got nginx running on opensuse tumbleweed with codeigniter application.

I get to the front page with no problem but any attempt open a controller fails with 404 error.

When I was working on Ubuntu I was able to solve this within minutes with a little bit of googling, but here for some reason I am struggling. I am attaching my default config file for nginx. There must be something I am really not seeing here, since I got this working in the past. Is nginx on opensuse really such a pain?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    index index.php;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        ## Handling of CORS
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        #
        # Om nom nom cookies
        #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        }
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, I eventually found and answer to the problem. I have pretty much completely erased the the contents of the config file and replaced them with what I found on nginx website ([here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/#)).

Funny thing is, if you notice there are no more directives for handling CORS in the config file, yet all the contents such as fonts, scripts, etc. are working fine without a glitch on localhost.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    autoindex on;
    index index.php;

    location / {

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

            location = /index.php {

                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
            }
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 444;
        }

}
```

Hope that will be of use to someone ;)